# compare two .strings file for finding missing keywords

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two .strings files in my application for supporting both persian and english language in my app.

For example I below files

en.strings:

```
"HELLO"="heloo";
"THANKS" = "thanks";
```

and another one

fa.strings:

```
"HELLO"="سلام";
```

Is there any tools in xcode that let me know that fa file do not contain `THANKS` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually export and import localisation files, xCode will set them for you, as well as deleting the unused ones. No need for any tool.

Comment: export and import them? may you please specify more?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html go to "export" section you just export the files, then you import them, it should generate the missing keywords.